# Scale vertical constraint with Autolayout

Tags: ios, iphone, interface-builder, ios-autolayout

The layout build in IB is currently looking like this for an iPhone 7:

[image: Current iPhone 7]

However when, with constraints, I switch to a 4s it looks like this with the content hanging off the view:

[image: Current iPhone 4s]

This is how it should look on an 4s:

[image: Should look like 4s]

Is it possible using IB and Autolayout to scale the vertical constraints so that the stack views fit the current view?

Comment: You should set up a bottom constraint for the last view.

Comment: @the4kman If I setup a bottom constraint for the last view, the other constraints don't scale and are ambiguous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have two options to perform what you want to do. I will post pictures of these: 
[image: Fixed heights With One Relative]

In this case, I've given all the views a fixed height, except for one of them (at the bottom) that just has a top, bottom, left and right.

In this case, you can't have multiple views with fully relative constraints because the OS will have a wide range of values to choose between when giving these views their layouts. Because of this range, the OS considers that the view positions are ambiguous. If you give all but one of them a fixed height, it will know exactly how much height to give the remaining view.

[image: Tops to above View and to SuperView]

Your other case is to give each View a top relative to the above view, and to the superview. From my understanding, this tells the OS how far each view is from one another, but also how for it is from the top of the screen. So with these two values, it can place the view at the right place.

Personally, I prefer to use the first way, I find it simpler.

Comment: I haven't got my items in a scrollview, I assume its the same with a normal view? Would I add the bottom constraint to my bottommost stack view?

Comment: I'm sorry I misunderstood with the scrollView, I'm updating my answer to consider this.